# Exectuting system lock script through Python

Tags: php, python, command-line-interface

I am trying to lock a `microsoft windows` system from a `php` script that calls a `python` script.

PHP Script:

```
<?php
system("C:/Python27/pythonw.exe C:/wamp/www/lock.py");
?>
```

Python Script:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
```

it is not locking the system...
what should i do ??

Comment: first of all I don't know why you used `pythonw.exe`. I tryed your code and didn't work, but when I used `python,exe` it worked when I called `php` from command line but still no luck from browser calls.

Comment: is there any way to make it work from browser ??

Comment: my aim is to excecute php script from browser which locks the pc...

Comment: I am working on it. and searching for possible problems and solutions

Comment: also you don't need to use a python code to lock your system, a simple `rundll32.exe` will do the trik: `<?php exec('rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation'); ?>` but still no luck on finding a way to call it through browser